# Jquery continues running even after URL redirect on Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, redirect

```
$('#target').click(function() {
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
return false;
});
```

How can I tell chrome and all other browsers to stop what they're doing and immediately redirect to another web page?

Firefox 8.0 executes the window.location.replace immediately, as I want it to.

When I step through the code above, Chrome 15.0.874.121 flies right past the window.location code and the return false and then moves into subsequent Jquery functions (in other words, Chrome completes the entire call stack and THEN replaces the URL)

I'm trying to execute the redirect in a number of different areas, the biggest problem is that the additional Jquery can add 3-5 SECONDS of time to the redirects, especially from within an .ajax success call.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and have no javascript errors

I've tried:

- putting 'return false' everywhere
- using different redirects (location.reload(true), location.href, etc)
- moving my redirect all the way outside of any other function
- Moving my redirect to a separate function altogether

No matter what I do, Chrome refuses to simply GO to another web site without finishing its call stack first. Please help.

Comment: Interesting, `window.location = 'http://www.google.com';` is also producing errors for me :o Have you considered opening a new window and closing the current?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in either the above code or the test() function example below, can you do a jsfiddle that replicates the issue you're having?  I'm using Chrome 15.0.874.121 and Firefox 8.0.1.

Comment: @Consciousness: I've opened new windows, rebooted, upgraded chrome, cleared cache and cookies....... all to no avail :(

Comment: jsfiddle does not do the redirect, but when I run the code I see BOTH messages, even though it should give one alert then redirect (http://jsfiddle.net/YKnqY/4/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#target').click(function() {
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
//THROW an exception is the only solution I've found so far
throw "Reloading Page";
});
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a better answer. It is NOT a jquery issue after all. I've trimmed everything down: removed all extensions in chrome, removed all external files, made a completely blank .html file with bare minimum javascript and a simple onclick... and Chrome STILL blasted through the redirect.

SO: As of now, my only answer is to throw an exception to tell Chrome to stop running JS just after the redirect.

Thanks to [Gijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713326/gijs)

Edit: Unfortunately, Chrome pauses on thrown exceptions be default so this turns out to not actually be a deployable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple Javascript and only do

```
document.location = "http://google.com";
```

Comment: Ultimately this needs to run after a bunch of other code inside of a div click. I'm using Jquery to handle all of that very successfully. Even when I call a standard javascript function to do the redirect from within the Jquery, chrome keeps chugging along.

Comment: `function test() {
alert('test');
setTimeout("test()","1000");
}
test();
document.location = 'http://www.google.com';` - triggers twice instead of once in chrome.

Comment: Well, that is weird, I am under Chrome 16 and I do not experience such an issue with either code.

Comment: I just updated chrome then; same issues with all the commands.

Comment: I also get the test alert twice when I run your code. My problem is that, even with using your code (but putting the document.location inside and at the end of the test() function)..... Chrome will still wait until AFTER the test() function is COMPLETE before redirecting.... When I attach test() to an onClick event on a link, Chrome does test() then waits until AFTER the onClick event is finished before redirecting. =(

Comment: I just upgraded to Chrome 16.0.912.63 and Chrome still steps past any sort of redirect, finishing the call stack before changing URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)?

```
$('#target').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yup, I've tried it...  Chrome continues to run through the call stack :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I ended up using an if else block and it worked.

Coffeescript

```
if Number(deck.length) == Number(deck.counter)
     window.location.href = "/rounds" 
else
    whatever...
```

Javascript

```
if (Number(deck.length) === Number(deck.counter)) {
      return window.location.href = "/rounds";
    } else {
```