# Chrome continues loading resources even after redirect with window.location

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Given the following HTML/JS:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location = '/another-url';
    </script>

    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="image.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Chrome will send resource requests for styles.css and image.png even though they come after what should be a page redirect. My understanding is that browsers should be loading top-to-bottom. Is there some reason for this, and is there a workaround to make sure these requests aren't being sent?

FWIW, Safari works as I would expect it to. Not sure about other browsers.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499158/jquery-continues-running-even-after-url-redirect-on-chrome) from 2011 suggests wrapping the window.location call in a if-else block solves this in Chrome.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the content if you are going to do an automatic redirect? Or even better do the redirect server side

Comment: @charlietfl I agree that's ideal but I'm in a static (serverless) scenario where I don't have a real server-side to speak of.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to another page (whether by setting `location`, clicking a link, or any other mechanism) doesn't unload the original page right away.

The browser will continue displaying (and loading) the original page until it starts receiving a response from the new page.

The most important reason for this is in case the new page serves a `204 No Content` response, in which the browser will stay on the original page.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose this makes sense. So there's no way to *force* it to stop?